# CSS Fluid Navigation

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I am trying to make the navigation section of my site responsive but cannot seem to get it to work the way I want to. Best way is to view the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Margate/mK4hw/) and see what I mean.

Currently when the browser is re-sized the blue div contracts until it meets the black div. The black div remains where it is and scroll bars appear! What I actually want this to do is for the red divs to be pushed left when the black and blue divs touch whenever the window is re-sized. When the window continues to shrink and the red divs are pushed left they will stop moving as soon as they touch the green div (scroll bars to appear).

I have tried converting things to %'s and changed the positioning but just cannot work this out! I need to learn and understand how this works before I am able to continue withe rest of the site.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fluid</title>

    <style>
        #container{position: relative; margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; max-width: 1000px; border: 2px solid blue;}
        #logo-and-nav-bar{position: relative; width: 750px; height: 175px; margin: 0px auto; border: 2px solid black;}      
        #logo {position: absolute; top: 5px; width: 200px; height: 70px; border: 2px solid green; text-align: center;}
        #nav-bar-upper, #nav-bar-lower {position: absolute; margin-left: 36%; width: 470px; border: 2px solid red;}
        #nav-bar-upper{top: 5px;}
        #nav-bar-lower{top: 65px;}
        #nav-bar-upper > ul > li, #nav-bar-lower > ul > li {display: inline; padding: 0 8px 0 8px; list-style: none;}
        #blower{position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 600px; border: 2px solid red;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="logo-and-nav-bar">
    <div id="logo">.jpeg Logo<br />In Here!</div>

        <div id="nav-bar-upper">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item D</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item E</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item F</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="nav-bar-lower">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Item G</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item H</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item I</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item J</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item K</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item L</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
       <div id="blower">Tel: 1234 56789</div> 
</div>  

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```css
#logo-and-nav-bar {
    width: 750px;
}
#nav-bar-upper, #nav-bar-lower {
    margin-left: 36%;
}
```

use

```css
#logo-and-nav-bar{
    width: 750px;
    min-width: 680px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#nav-bar-upper, #nav-bar-lower {
    right: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mK4hw/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Thing is I want to keep the layout the same as it is in the example but I want to the red divs to move left when the blue div meets the inner black div. So when blue and black meet they continue to shrink and the red divs are pushed left... Hope this makes sense?

Comment: @Margate Isn't it the behavior of the Demo?

Comment: Appologies! I have just re-checked the demo and yes! That is what I am trying to do. Not sure what happened when I checked it before but this what I am trying to do yes. This is excellent. Just one more thing though, how do I change the blower div to move at the same fluid amount as the nav-bar-upper, #nav-bar-lower divs?

Comment: @Margate Just add `right: 0` to `#blower` too. And consider using `bottom: 0` instead of `top: 150px`.

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much for your time and fiddle. I have learned and hope this will help other as well to learn. :  )